# Add more levels to the Table of Contents web part?

Tags: 2010, web-part

Is it possible to add more levels in `Content -> Levels to show` in the OOTB Table of Contents web part? Could this be edited in some file or do I need to build a custom web part in order to get more levels displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to export the webpart, edit the property 'levelToShow (
`<property name="LevelsToShow" type="int">10</property>`) and import the webpart again.

You probably want to update the XSL-stylesheet as well, to accomadate for the extra levels.

(Don't change the settings with 'edit webpart' afterwards, you will overwrite the levelsToShow value.)

Comment: Thanks! I initially had problems with exporting the web part (the option didn't show up) but after doing a IISRESET it showed and it worked out just as you suggested.